# Django project doesn't work on the VPS with a port, gunicorn+ nginx

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn

I have Django project on my VPS. When I check my website in the browser I get an error: 1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: XX.XXX.XXX.XX, server: mysite.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:6112/", host: "mysite.com"

```
upstream app_server_wsgiapp {
  server 127.0.0.1:6112 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    server_name mysite.com www.mysite.com;
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/static/;
    }
    location /media/ {
        alias /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/media/;
    }
    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://app_server_wsgiapp;
    }
    charset off;
    disable_symlinks if_not_owner from=$root_path;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-includes/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/vhosts-resources/mysite.com/*.conf;
    access_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.access.log;
    error_log /var/www/httpd-logs/mysite.com.error.log notice;
    set $root_path /var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com;
    root $root_path;
    listen XX.XXX.XX.XXX:80;
}
```

/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service

```
[Unit]
Description=mysite daemon
Requires=mysite.socket
After=network.target

[Service]
User=www-root
Group=root
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/mysiteproject
ExecStart=/var/www/www-root/data/www/mysite.com/public_html/mysiteenv/bin/gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6112 mysitepr.wsgi:application

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/systemd/system/mysite.socket

```
[Unit]
Description=mysite socket

[Socket]
ListenStream=/run/mysite.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target
```

systemctl status mysite

```
● mysite.service - mysite daemon
     Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mysite.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-12-07 18:54:42 CET; 16min ago
TriggeredBy: ● mysite.socket
   Main PID: 4360 (gunicorn)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 1843)
     Memory: 45.1M
     CGroup: /system.slice/mysite.service
```

journalctl -u mysite.socket

```
Dec 07 18:41:50 systemd[1]: mysite.socket: Failed with result 'service-start-limit-hit'.
Dec 07 18:42:41  systemd[1]: Starting mysite socket.
Dec 07 18:42:41  systemd[1]: Listening on mysite socket.
Dec 07 18:46:59 systemd[1]: mysite.socket: Succeeded.
Dec 07 18:46:59  systemd[1]: Closed mysite socket.
Dec 07 18:46:59  systemd[1]: Stopping mysite socket.
Dec 07 18:46:59  systemd[1]: Listening on mysite socket.
```

I checked it works if I start it in the terminal via Gunicorn

```
gunicorn --bind 0.0.0.0:6112 mysitepr.wsgi
```

And if I check it in terminal I get my main html page as should be.

```
curl --unix-socket /run/mysite.sock localhost
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I would try checking gunicorn logs to see if there is something wrong there, e.g. via journalctl - https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/57243. BTW, I see that Nginx is configured to connect to gunicorn via HTTP (TCP port). Then why do you configure gunicorn to also listen to UNIX socket?

Comment: @EugenePrikazchikov could you help me to find a guide for it? I added the journalctl

Comment: Try configuring nginx to connect with gunicorn via socket, not port (not sure why you have both of them there). I.e.: `server unix:/run/mysite.sock fail_timeout=0;`